# ChromeDriver Will not run (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote code like this but this code isn't running the chromedriver and i have added the file(chromedriver.exe) with this path (\chromedrive\chromedriver.exe).

```
public class Browser {
    private static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public static WebDriver driver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public static void open(String url) {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path + "\\chromedrive\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Page extends LoadableComponent<Page> {

    static String url = "http://-------";

    private static String title = "title";

    public Page() {
        PageFactory.initElements(Browser.driver(), this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void load() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Browser.open(url);
    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        assertTrue(Browser.driver().getTitle().equals(title));
    }
}
```

.

```
public class PageTests {
    @Test
    public void pageTest() {
        Page page = new Page();
        page.get();
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver
>   executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;

Comment: Why you used Separate "path" variable to define driver's path.If you know where you installed your chromeDriver,why don't you provide it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Initially i think you are creating the Chromedriver, without the reference to the exe being there.

So if you change it into something like this, it will probaly work.

```
public class Browser {
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver driver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public static void open(String url) {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path + "\\chromedrive\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); //Initilize here
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've tried that but NullPointerException occurred in 'assertTrue(Browser.driver().getTitle().equals(title));' and chromedriver still not run.(bad english sorry T.T)

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct then? Have you tried with an aboslute path like "C:\\MyWebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe" and ensure your webdriver is at that location.

Comment: yes, i checked the path. 
if wrote code like this, chromedriver is run
`
 public class Page {
 private String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 ...

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path + "\\chromedrive\\chromedriver.exe");
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
 ...
 }

 @Test
 public void pageTest() {
 ...
 }
...
}
`

Answer (score 1):

When your application loads the first time, it'll try to load the Browser class.

While  loading a class the JVM will do all the static initializing that is specified, in this case it'll try to create a ChromeDriver object, because you're initializing the static field with `new ChromeDriver()`. At that point your `open` method hasn't been called yet to set the system property, so an exception will be thrown, which causes the JVM to quit.

To fix this, either create the ChromeDriver object /after/ setting the system property (e.g. in your `open` method) or set the system property when starting the JVM:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path/to/driver -jar somejar.jar
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!, but i don't understand that create the ChromeDriver object /after/ setting the system property. please explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

You should instantiate you browser inside the function you are defining and setting the path.

try this:

```
  public static void open(String url) {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path + "\\chromedrive\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
}
```

There is no need of separately creating a driver function.please remove it.

Comment: And what is the reason for this argument? The driver object will still be on the heap, so nothing will change.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Copy the version number in the Eclipse console e.g. **116.0.5845.111**

eclipse console
[DEBUG] Result: Version=**116.0.5845.111**

Step 2: Create a new folder inside the win64 with a folder name you copied in the eclipse console
C:\Users\yourUSER\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64

Step 3: Download the specific chrome driver version and copy inside the new folder you have created

Step 4: Go to C:\Users\yourUSER\.cache\selenium and edit the file **resolution.properties**

inside the resolution properties:

add this code:

**chrome116=116.0.5845.111
chrome116-ttl=11:23:04 31/08/2023 CST**

see photo for the example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghmjK.png)